# Tinned copper for SPI?

Tags: led, spi, cables, wire, led-strip

I'm currently doing some repairs on a project that requires linking 1m strips of APA102C LED pixels in series to form a grid. I've always used bare copper for this purpose, avoiding the tinned copper RGB wire that's available all over the place. In this case, though, I think something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015VBCBSQ) will make my life a whole lot easier.

My understanding is that this stuff is intended for use with single color RGB strips, but I've found it on the end of just about every reel of addressable pixels I've ever purchased. However, I'm driving my strips at 3MHz, so I'm scared of the skin effect. Can anybody offer some perspective on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has wires serving two different purposes, though likely the same physical type of wire can be used for both.

What is running at "3 MHz" is the *data* signalling, which should require relatively modest current, really just to drive the characteristic impedance of the line and the input capacitance of the *first* chip (as the signal sent to the next is then regenerated).  It is true that at a high signal rate, there will be a "skin effect" in the conductor (and associated ground return), however that isn't really a problem, since the current will be low - the thin annular cross section where the current flows will be ample.

The other thing carried in your multi-wire cable is the DC power to the LEDs, but this should change only at a relatively slow rate, so doesn't really have high frequency content and a skin effect.   Hopefully the variation of current required over time due to the PWM of the LEDs is absorbed in local capacitance (otherwise you would have a source of radio interference).

Now, you might still wonder what happens if the same ground wire is providing the return for both the high data rate signal and the LED power.  It turns out this does not make skin effect an issue either.  As long as the wire can be said to be a *linear* medium (which for practical purposes, is as long as it doesn't get so hot that the conductivity changes substantially), the high-rate data current has no impact on the resistance felt by the slowly changing LED current - the outer ring of copper will carry both data and power return, while the core will carry only power return.

However, the situations are not *entirely* independent.  Voltage drop in the ground caused by drawing high power currents through it *will* affect the voltage seen by the data receiver.  Typically that is within the noise margins of digital signalling - though if there were no local power filtering capacitance and the cable were very long, it is possible that the PWM current could cause enough `ground bounce` to interfere with the data signalling.

Comment: Interesting. If I'm understanding you correctly: since the current on my data lines is very low, higher current density in the more resistive portion of the wire is unlikely to effect enough voltage drop to violate the input thresholds of the chips. I hadn't even considered the effect of data and power lines sharing the same ground. Thanks!